# Mercurial HG pull specific "no changes" yet files different

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

My local file and mercurial revision are at different stages however hg pull & hg update default returns a no changes message.

On bitbucket my repo and revision I am trying to pull to local machine is https://bitbucket.org/sayth/pyxml/src/c63b5ce2119ae64331ee2551fc19083315be0571/xrace.py

```
[sayth@localhost pyXML]$ hg pull && hg update default 
pulling from https://bitbucket.org/sayth/pyxml
searching for changes
no changes found
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

At bitbucket at latest revision you can see just in the imports alone they are different.

**Bitbucket**

```
# from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
import argparse
import os
```

**local machine**

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
# import pandas as pd
# import psycopg2
import argparse
import os
# from datetime import datetime
```

Even trying pulling by revision number but it wont update.

```
[sayth@localhost pyXML]$ hg pull -r c63b5ce
pulling from https://bitbucket.org/sayth/pyxml
no changes found
```

Comment: Is your local file definitely committed, or is it the working copy? It sounds like revision c63b5ce already exists in your local clone, if you do hg log -r c63b5ce and get coherent values then it does.

Comment: Yes it's the working copy, how is that different to current file?

Comment: The current file that you're editing is the working copy. What is the output if you do hg status? Do you see the file in question listed?

Comment: (fluent) [sayth@localhost pyXML]$ hg log -r c63b5ce 
changeset:   4:c63b5ce2119a
user:        sayth <flebber.crue@gmail.com>
date:        Tue Jun 21 06:04:54 2016 +1000
summary:     some iteration

hg status doesn't return anything

Comment: (fluent) [sayth@localhost pyXML]$ hg identify
8c87107ddc0e tip

Comment: OK, so your current working copy is based off of 8c87107ddc0e. If you want to change your working copy to c63b5ce2119a you should do `hg update -r c63b5ce2119a`

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clone is a full copy of the remote repository with all the revisions in it.
When you **pull** you're checking the remote repo for any new revisions and copying them to your local clone, but it does not change the files that you are currently editing.

**update** changes your working copy, i.e. the files you are currently editing to whatever revision you choose.
If you just do `hg update` without specifying a revision it will update to whatever it thinks is the current tip of the repo.
If you do `hg update -r c63b5ce2119a` it will update your working copy to the specified revision and that will change the files you are currently editing.

Comment: Run into the same... This is the weirdest behaviour you would never expect of a VCS