# hg pull do not retreive changes

Tags: mercurial

I've been using *hg* for a few years with a *BitBucket Repo*. I use it to archive my development but also to synchronise between different computers (mainly my desktop and my main laptop). So far, no troubles.

But today, when I did an `hg pull` to get the latest version from the server, I got the response "*no changes found*", when I can see the changes made yesterday on the server, and still no replicated on my files, locally.

I eventually got the latest version using `hg graft -r the_latest_version`, which solve my problem for now ... however this was easy to see as it was for a shell script with only a few files.

With projects with plenty of files, I might not spot the problem early enough. Any ideas on what went wrong and how to correct it ?

Cheers.

Comment: `pull` is requesting changes from a remote repository. But it does NOT do any changes to your local repository (unless you also specify `--update`). `graft` on the other hand creates a new changeset by copying the specified revision. If you can use `graft`, the revision clearly was already in your local repository. Sounds to me like you got yourself confused with what version you currently had checked-out and copied a revision from one branch to another. Mercurial does not automatically update between branches when using a simple `hg update`. Give the revision explicitly in that case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial HG pull specific "no changes" yet files different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943636/mercurial-hg-pull-specific-no-changes-yet-files-different)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is: I just forgot I needed to perform `hg update` after `hg pull` !

Thanks to @planetmaker for pointing in the right direction !

Sorry for the disturbance!